# Convert ArrayList<Custom> to gson in Java Android

Tags: java, android, gson

Good afternoon.
I can not understand why the code does not work after publishing in the Google market.
Before publishing in android studio code

```
ArrayList<TableAccount> tableAccount = getTableAccount();
String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(tableAccount);
```

result:

```
Log.d(TAG, "RESULT: " + jsonStr);
RESULT: [{"name":"payment","valueFloat":0.0,"valueInt":0,"valueStr":"no"}]
```

But, after posting, I see:

```
Log.d(TAG, "RESULT: " + jsonStr);
RESULT: [{"a":"payment","b":"no","c":0,"d":0.0}]
```

Why do the letters a b c appear?

And where do the keys disappear? ["name", "valueFloat", "valueInt", "valueStr"]

Comment: Do you see the problem with a `release` build tested locally? If so, then perhaps you turned on obfuscation with ProGuard/R8. You would either need to turn that off, or configure it to avoid these classes, or use `@SerializedName` to override the reflection and teach Gson how to name things. Also, note that Gson is a bit out of date -- consider switching to Moshi.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. Everything worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you turned on ProGuard/R8 for your `release` build, and its obfuscation mode renamed your fields.

The biggest lesson from here is to make sure that you test your `release` builds before uploading them to Google Play.

To fix the problem, you could:

- Turn off ProGuard/R8 entirely,
- Leave it on but disable obfuscation entirely,
- Leave it on but disable obfuscation for these specific classes, or
- Use `@SerializedName` annotations to teach Gson what names to use, instead of its default of using Java reflection to look up the names of the fields (as obfuscation renames those fields)